# Why is Google Analytics using "sampling" to produce the All Campaigns report for multiple days?

Tags: google-analytics

I recently discovered the Acquisition > Campaigns > All Campaigns report is usually sampled in our Google Analytics. If I reduce the date range to 1 or 2 days, it might be unsampled, but even some single days are showing sampling.

I've gone through the [GA page on sampling](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en) and nothing seems applicable. We do not have the Users and Active Users metrics enabled, it is not a Google Ads report, and it is not modified in any way from the default: I have no segments applied, have not changed the primary dimension or added a secondary dimension, have not clicked through on any entry, and have not filtered the table.

Everything I can find indicates this report should not be sampled regardless of date range. Is there another explanation I am missing?

Comment: Is it problematic that sampling is applied?  Sampling usually gives pretty good data for large date ranges.

Comment: You say that "nothing seems applicable", yet you are creating an ad-hoc report by changing the date range.

Comment: It's mostly confusing. Sampling applies even with the default date range, and I've also never had a date-range change introduce sampling on an otherwise unmodified standard report. We don't need exact numbers for this, though we were interested in a low-traffic set of campaigns, so the sampling isn't too painful but... it just seems like it shouldn't be happening if our setup is correct.